# How to determine bifurcation diagram for following system of difference equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, graphing-functions, bifurcation, mathematical-biology

So given this system, $\begin{gather*}N_{t+2}=N_t\exp[r(1-\frac{N_t}{K})]\frac{1-e^{-aP_t}}{aP_t}\\ P_{t+1}=N_t[1-\frac{1-e^{-aP_t}}{aP_t}]\end{gather*}$, how do I determine the bifurcation diagram? The varying parameter is $a$, and trying to determine an explicit form of $N$ and $P$ in terms of $a$ has turned out to be fruitless. If anyone has any pointers or know of any matlab recipe that can do it, please comment below

Comment: Are you sure it is $N_{t+\textbf{2}}$? And $aP$ in the denominator, shouldn't that be $aP_t$? If not, what is the value of $P$? Do you have any hint on starting values, i.e., $N_0$ and $P_0$. What about the constants $K$ and $r$, what are appropriate values for those constants?

Comment: I have fixed the denominator issue, but no $N_{t+2}$ is the right form on the other inquiry

Comment: In that case I am afraid I cannot help you as I have no idea how $N_{t+1}$ is to be computed.

Comment: r=2.5 and K=2500